# Can I do these kind of questions? “Who is your brother and where is he?”

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can we join two questions in one using *and*? Or do we need to separate both questions ?

Comment: You can do that in any language. Not that I know all languages, but the few I know allow it.

Comment: It *could* be written as two sentences - *Who is your brother? And where is he?* I suggest the OP's "run-on" format should only be used if there's no significant pause in the ***spoken*** version. The OP's example is rather "unusual", but [*Who are you and what do you want?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Who+are+you+and+what+do+you+want%22) has been written many times with both orthographies. Plus the two-sentence version where the second sentence *doesn't* start with ***And***.

Comment: While the question I gave as a duplicate isn't an exact match, the answers cover your situation well.

Comment: "Who are you and what have you done with Hermione Granger?" is one of Ron Weasley's finest lines. "Why isn't the Government doing more to combat global warming and did you wash your hands before eating your tea?" is equally grammatical but unacceptably pairs two irreconcilably disparate topics in a single sentence.